# How select for update works for queries with multiple rows/results?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select-for-update

So given this transaction:

```
select * from table_a where field_a = 'A' for update;
```

Assuming this gives out multiple rows/results, will the database lock all the results right off the bat? Or will it lock it one row at a time.

If the later is true, does that mean running this query concurrently, can result in a deadlock?

Thus, adding an order by to maintain consistency on the order is needed to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you find more information on this, select projections happen before order-by calls (subject to optimization) but it's not clear at what point the FOR UPDATE locks are taken, if it's after realization then order by should be fine, if it's as it processes each rows select, then it would need a CTE to do the ordering before final select. This is a nightmare one to replicate. 5+yrs old but any insight you've gained since making this post please do share.Thanks

Comment: Nevermind. I see from EXPLAIN ANALYZE that Lock Rows happened after the Sort, I didn't expect to see LockRows in the report, but very handy and clear that it is there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/explicit-locking.html) explains what happens as follows:

> FOR UPDATE
>
> `FOR UPDATE` causes the rows retrieved by the `SELECT` statement to be
>   locked as though for update. This prevents them from being locked,
>   modified or deleted by other transactions until the current
>   transaction ends. That is, other transactions that attempt `UPDATE`,
>   `DELETE`, `SELECT FOR UPDATE`, `SELECT FOR NO KEY UPDATE`, `SELECT FOR SHARE` 
>   or `SELECT FOR KEY SHARE` of these rows will be blocked until
>   the current transaction ends; conversely, `SELECT FOR UPDATE` will
>   wait for a concurrent transaction that has run any of those commands
>   on the same row, and will then lock and return the updated row (or no
>   row, if the row was deleted). Within a `REPEATABLE READ` or
>   `SERIALIZABLE` transaction, however, an error will be thrown if a row
>   to be locked has changed since the transaction started. For further
>   discussion see Section 13.4.

The direct answer to your question is that Postgres cannot lock all the rows "right off the bat"; it has to find them first.  Remember, this is row-level locking rather than table-level locking.

The documentation includes this note:

> `SELECT FOR UPDATE` modifies selected rows to mark them locked, and so
>   will result in disk writes.

I interpret this as saying that Postgres executes the `SELECT` query and as it finds the rows, it marks them as locked.  The lock (for a given row) starts when Postgres identifies the row.  It continues until the end of the transaction.

Based on this, I think it is possible for a deadlock situation to arise using `SELECT FOR UPDATE`.